# Creating a nested treeview

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, treeview

**Note:**

I [previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42032305/creating-a-treeview-from-nested-json-response) this question, but no longer have access to the account nor do I have the ability to recover the account. If a moderator is viewing this, please delete my previous question.

**Question:**

I'm using [AndroidTreeView library](https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView) to create a TreeView of messages (essentially nested layouts).

In my code, I have a JSON response that looks something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "user_id": 1,
        "message": "Hello",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "user_id": 2,
                "message": "Hi",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "user_id": 3,
                        "message": "Hey",
                        "children": [

                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "user_id": 2,
                "message": "Bye",
                "children": [

                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "user_id": 2,
        "message": "Heya",
        "children": [

        ]
    }
]
```

As you can see, the data can be nested and can have multiple children under each message. Each object (including the children) is of the class Message.java (the Gson model class), which contains the following:

```
public class Message implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("user_id")
    @Expose
    private Integer userId;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("children")
    @Expose
    private List<Message> children = null;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Integer userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public List<Message> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(List<Message> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }
}
```

In order to build the tree, here is the code I have so far (in MainActivity.java):

```
private List<Message> messages = response.body(); // the JSON response

private TreeNode root = TreeNode.root();

for (Message message : messages) {
    MessageAdapter.TreeItem messageItem = new MessageAdapter.TreeItem(message);
    TreeNode parentNode = new TreeNode(messageItem).setViewHolder(new MessageAdapter(MainActivity.this));
    root.addChild(parentNode);
}

LinearLayout messageContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.messageContainer);

AndroidTreeView tView = new AndroidTreeView(MainActivity.this, root);
messageContainer.addView(tView.getView());

And here is the MessageAdapter.java:

public class MessageAdapter extends TreeNode.BaseNodeViewHolder<MessageAdapter.TreeItem> {
    private Context context;

    private TextView messageTextView;

    public MessageAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View createNodeView(TreeNode node, TreeItem value) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.message_layout, null, false);

        Message message = value.message;

        messageTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
        messageTextView.setText(message.getMessage());

        return view;
    }

    public static class TreeItem {
        public Message message;

        public TreeItem(Message message) {
            this.message = message;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with my code is that it only outputs "Hello" and "Heya" (the two top-most messages):

```
- Hello
- Heya
```

Instead, it should be outputting:

```
- Hello
    - Hi
        - Hey
    - Bye
- Heya
```

How can I change my code to loop through all of the nested children messages and add them to each node properly?

FYI, this is how a child node is added to a parent node (taken from the library readme):

```
TreeNode parent = new TreeNode("MyParentNode");
TreeNode child0 = new TreeNode("ChildNode0");
TreeNode child1 = new TreeNode("ChildNode1");
parent.addChildren(child0, child1);
root.addChild(parent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I don't think you need to have a `List<Messages>` it will be easier to just convert the JSON into a tree.

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
     root.addChild(decodeMessages(arr.getJSONObject(i)));
}

private String decodeMessages(JSONObject jsonObject) {
    TreeNode treeNode;
    // decode message from json
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("children");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            treeNode.addChild(decodeMessages(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return treeNode;
}
```

Comment: I'd rather use `List<Messages>` because I refer to it elsewhere in my code as well.